# jQuery Add & Remove Class Div Width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i add/remove class according as div width ? I tried some codes but I have no idea about jquery codes. I'd like add div class according as antoher div width. Just i need add class like that. If container is smaller than 600px "add class" to content div else "remove class" from content div. These are my codes;

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>

$(window).resizeboxes(function() {
if ($(".container").width < 600){
    $( ".content" ).addClass( ".content_600" );
    }
});
else{
  removeClass('.content_600')
}
$(window).trigger('resizeboxes');
```

Comment: Plus one for jQuery! :3

Comment: How are you going to use this? CSS styling only or JS? Why and how is `div` width changed?

Comment: Have you put any though into using media queries? 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: for this purpose exactly you have .toggleClass(), with the second parameter. check my answer :-)

Comment: Also, in the 'else' section of your code, you're missing the $(".content") part before the 'removeClass('.content_600')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, though the code is changed slightly. There were some problems with the syntax also, so I've corrected those (for instance the else statement was slightly misplaced). Here is a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/vt0nbx36/3/

Here is the code:

```
var resizeboxes  = function() {
    if ($(".container").width() < 600)
    {
        $(".content").addClass("content_600");
    }
    else
    {
        $(".content").removeClass("content_600")
    }
};

resizeboxes();

$(window).resize(function(){
    resizeboxes();   
});
```

Comment: `addClass` / `removeClass` shouldnt use a dot in the class name. Alos useful to give some visual feedback when the class changes - helps the OP understand. I updated your fiddle with both: https://jsfiddle.net/vt0nbx36/2/

Comment: i accidentaly replaced your new fiddle with old one, please correct me

Answer (score 1):

For this need exactly, you have jQuery's **`.toggleClass()`** function. It takes the class name as a first parameter, and optional second boolean parameter that states wether the class name should be added or removed. You can find the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```
$(".content").toggleClass("content_600", ($(".container").width() < 600));
```

Answer (score 0):

Even tho your question is a JS related question, CSS as a matter of fact can handle this like no other beast can *(mostly)*!

CSS allows you to use media-queries to resize your content based on the width of the viewport.

The upside of this is that the browser will handle this for you within the rendering engine rather than having JS between your change and the rendering engine.

The major downside is that you can't define the width of element **A** based on element **B** but are unfortunately locked to using the viewport as an indicator.

Before I explain why you'd *want* to use CSS I'd like to point out why you *don't* want to use JS for this if possible.

The [`jQuery.resize`](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) eventhandler fires inconsistently across browsers and it fires alot of times usually.

This causes your scrolling to clog up and make your webpage feel laggy.
If there's anything your users will dislike it's the fact that scrolling is controlled by something they don't even know of which is slowing you down.

As for a CSS solution, a [media query](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) looks like this:

```
.my-selector {
    width: 900px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    .my-selector {
        width: 600px;
        ...
    }
}
```

You wrap your code in a *sort-of conditional* that allows you to be very flexible with manipulating elements on the page.

What happens in the above piece of code is that when the parser reads the CSS it sees the first selector not in a media query so it applies `width: 900px;` then it sees a media query and sees the other rule for `my-selector` **however** it will **only** apply that rule when the screen is at that width we defined in the `@media ...` rule. When you resize CSS handles things differently behind the scenes so it's much faster than JS in that case.

I'm not sure if it actually applies to your situation but if your container is sized by the viewport rather than parent elements this should be possible and I thought it'd be nice atleast to show you a good way of playing with element dimensions.

Also, you can use `@media` to for instance make a webpage print friendly by changing the `all` to `print` for example and setting the `background-color: transparent` for an element - **saves ink ^.^** which is an additional extra on top of the general awesomeness of media queries.

Hope it helps, good luck if you wish to make your webpage 5 times faster ;)

Comment: media queries only relate to the screen width, and not to his ".container" div's width

Comment: I understand but I do not think you read my entire answer tho, either way - fair enough.

Comment: I've read it, and you have some good points there regarding the performance issues, BUT, it has nothing to do with his question, and it does not answering his need. The (useful) information you provided should really be a comment to the question, rather than an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot put this much *comment* in an actual comment, but I don't mind downvotes anyways - It's more important that other users with a *similar* issue can also find a more performant solution when they land here. You are also correct about the question just being tagged differently but the exact situation is unclear, his element might be  percentage width in which case a media query would be perfectly fine but we do not know that anyways.

Comment: You get a +1 from me. Working with CSS and using % for height and width is better practice. Everything in his question can be achieved using just CSS and no scripting. Everyone knows fluid sites are the way forward now.

Comment: everyone __should__ know***

Comment: Much appriciated and while I don't fully agree that % width is always better as long as the content scales with a container you can use CSS instead of JS - I'd break any rule to share that knowledge :P